# What is --no-site-packages in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I am very new to python. I am trying to install virtualenv and create a sample project. 
I could see the option like `--no-site-packages`. I tried(`virtualenv myapp`) without specifying option and try to install flask package(`pip install flask`). It installs in the package in `lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask`.

What is the purpose of option `--no-site-packages`.

PS: Virtualenv version - `1.11.2`

Comment: This is the default behaviour since 2011 https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/1.8.3/ 1.7 (2011-11-30)

Answer (score 5):

virtualenv is used to create seperate environment for each project, based on its dependencies.
If `--no-site-packages` is not set, then the virtual envrironment will only contain symbolic links ( shortcuts) to the global site-packages.
If it is set, then it creates a copy of the site package to provide fully isolated environment.

Answer (score 4):

From the virtualenv man page:

```
--no-site-packages
   Don´t give access to the global site-packages modules to the virtual
   environment.
```