# virtualenv no longer has --no-site-packages option? How can I get the same effect?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Despite what various web pages say, and questions on Stackoverflow from 8 or more years ago say, `virtualenv` on MacOS Catalina (at least) appears to not recognize the `--no-site-packages` option.

Was the option removed some years ago? How do we get the same effect? As [this SO post says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527471/what-is-no-site-packages-in-virtualenv), the effect is:

> Don´t give access to the global site-packages modules to the virtual environment.

Could it be that now `--no-site-packages` is the default option, so doesn't have to be specified? How is it that I could still access my global `pip-check` package even after activating a virtualenv?

Answer (score 3):

Yup, `--no-site-packages` is indeed the default option now.